# How to use middleware with routing in FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I am following the FastAPI documentation [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) and trying to implement routing with a middleware.
My main contains:

```
app = FastAPI()


app.include_router(
    SomeService.router,
    prefix="/services",
    tags=["services"]
)


@app.middleware("http")
async def add_process_time_header(request: Request, call_next):
    start_time = time.time()
    response = await call_next(request)
    process_time = time.time() - start_time
    response.headers["X-Process-Time"] = str(process_time)
    return response
```

When sending a request, it is correctly executed and returns the right value but does not contain the value appended through the middleware.

I have tried defining the middleware inside the service route
and defining the middleware before app.include_router

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation about middleware](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/) mentions that if

> (...) you want a client in a browser to be able to see [the custom headers], you need to add them to your [CORS configurations](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/), using the parameter `expose_headers` documented in [Starlette's CORS docs](https://www.starlette.io/middleware/#corsmiddleware).

Comment: Yes and i have read that. It is working fine but a mistake on my behalf reading the headers.
Thanks